# Exim with MySQL lookup using regular expression

Tags: mysql, exim, regex

I have the following working Exim4 Router:

```
dovecot_user:
  driver = accept
    condition = ${lookup mysql{SELECT CONCAT(mailboxes.local_part,'@',domains.fqdn) AS goto FROM domains,mailboxes WHERE \
               mailboxes.local_part='${quote_mysql:$local_part}' AND \
               mailboxes.active=1 AND \
               mailboxes.domain_id=domains.id AND \
               domains.fqdn='${quote_mysql:$domain}' AND \
               domains.active=1}{yes}{no}}
 transport = dovecot_delivery
```

I would like to modify it so that it can accept addresses the of the forms (and deliver then to the `crm-bounce` inbox):

```
crm-bounce@domain.tld
crm-bounce+bounce_59510d24bce66@domain.tld
```

I know that the following SQL correctly selects from a test database:

```
SELECT * FROM regexptest.test WHERE email REGEXP '^crm-bounce([\+].*)?$';
```

I have modified the line:

```
mailboxes.local_part='${quote_mysql:$local_part}' AND \
```

so that it reads:

```
mailboxes.local_part REGEXP '^${quote_mysql:$local_part}([\+].*)?\$' AND \
```

but when running `exim -bt crm-bounce+b@domain.tld` I get `undeliverable: Unrouteable address`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was doing this all wrong. I neded to enable local_part_suffix in the router by adding:

```
local_part_suffix = +*
local_part_suffix_optional
```